# "To a fare-thee-well" for "perfectly well" in AE

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage, writing-style

Does the idiom "to a fare-thee-well" have any currency in modern day AE speech and writing, or does it have sort of an old fashioned feel to it?

> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fare-thee-well

If indeed it's in fairly common use, is it appropriate for whatever register?

Also --in expressions of suitability or appearance -- would it sound like as good an option as "like a charm", "like a glove", "a merveille", and "perfectly well"?

Consider the following examples:

> This jacket fits you to a fare-thee-well. [source](http://www.askandyaboutclothes.com/forum/showthread.php?62656-What-Are-You-Wearing-Today/page366)>/
>
> That's a terrific looking T-shirt. It fits you to a fare-thee-well. [source](http://sewing.patternreview.com/review/pattern/55052)>/
>
> And she was dressed to please in a below-the-knee filmy skirt and a v-necked blouse that fit her to a fare-thee-well. [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=unL5xeceVkQC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=%22fit+her+to+a+fare+thee+well%22&source=bl&ots=sn3H1xb4Qt&sig=ljqcUuxnCcYkcvjaGuAn00fbb8Q&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=y3AbU4quOYbRywPOt4GICg&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22fit%20her%20to%20a%20fare%20thee%20well%22&f=false)>/
>
> They're fully lined, watch pocketed, and will fit you to a fare-thee-well.
>   [source](http://www.newspapers.com/newspage/22514911/)>/
>
> Neat nylon pull-ons knit to fit you to a fare-thee-well.
>   [source](http://sjf.stparchive.com/Archive/SJF/SJF08171972P12.php)>/
>
> Godberg's description fits him to a fare thee well.
>   [source](http://startingstrength.com/resources/forum/showthread.php?t=30783&page=13)>/
>
> Cat Ballou (genial drunk) was quite a nice picture in his tight jeans, which fit him to a fare-thee-well.
>   [source](http://www.otterlimits.org/more/movies/wildone.html)>/
>
> They are beautiful, and fit me to a fare-thee-well.
>   [source](http://treeskin.dreamwidth.org/54691.html)>/
>
> Suits me to a fare-thee-well!
>   [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=gM5QTmqo5AwC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=%22suits+me+to+a+fare+thee+well%22&source=bl&ots=WUKg7F4S5v&sig=UCx0bqDeYFz75bL7KZ1-TBS8Ok8&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=Tn8bU_WIGsXhywOlhID4Dg&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22suits%20me%20to%20a%20fare%20thee%20well%22&f=false)>/
>
> ...off his triumphant role in the enchanting Moonlighy Kingdom, is back to his macho, smirking ways and the role suits him to a fare thee well.
>   [source](http://agourahills.patch.com/groups/opinion/p/looper-39ff1a14)>/

Comment: It's a "folksy, mock-archaic" US colloquialism. Apparently the more "modern" form ***fare-you-well*** was actually [more common a century ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fare-thee-well%2Cfare-you-well&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfare%20-%20thee%20-%20well%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfare%20-%20you%20-%20well%3B%2Cc0), but obviously that just doesn't sound "quaint" enough to the latter-day revivalists.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My Norfolk grandparents used to say 'fare-yer-well' at parting.

Comment: I'm wondering where you heard or saw this to even suspect that it might be current usage. I've never seen it before in my life and wouldn't have figured out the meaning from context – I would have assumed it was an error!

Comment: @BraddSzonye it's quoted as an Americanisms in most comprehensive bilingual dictionaries out here.

Comment: Perhaps you need a resource that does a better job of presenting current information rather than comprehensive information? Again, I recommend asking for help on [meta].

Comment: @WS2: That's a different "mock-archaic" usage (even regionally, I doubt it had continuous currency ever since mainstream usage had become reduced to *"Farewell"*). OP's one is a completely different sense, but I don't know how it came about (perhaps a whimsical variant of *"fairly well"*, or mispronunciation of *"very well"*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers My grandmother who I clearly remember using it had been born in 1882, at a time when Thomas Hardy was publishing his novels. I can't actually quote any instance from Hardy, but 'fare-thee-well' would not sound to me archaic for that period.

Comment: @WS2: Well, Hardy's mainly noted for his "Wessex novels", which are pretty much the other end of the country. To be honest, even though he was very much recording "dying/dead" usages & customs, I don't recall much in the way of "thee-ing and thou-ing" in his stuff - it's been more a Northern thing for centuries. Whatever - NGrams tells me *fare thee well* peaked around the 1820s, but relatively speaking it's always "flatlined" against *farewell*. Maybe it wasn't exactly "archaic" in dialectal Norfolk in your youth, but it certainly was in the country at large by the start of the last century.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Fare-thee-well" is not used in modern AE.  Instead of "to a fare-thee-well" we would just say "fairly well".

Notatation from FumbleFingers:

> According to OED, the US colloquialism "fare-you-well" dates back to
>   at least 1884, defined as to the last point; to the utmost degree;
>   completely. From which I'm tempted to suspect the original such usage
>   was an allusion to the fact that "Farewell" is often the last word (we
>   still say today that such-and-such is "the last word" [in high
>   fashion, or whatever]). But the (very limited) "revival" in recent
>   years might easily be influenced by assonance with very/fairly well.

Comment: It doesn't mean the same thing. And never did, as far as I can see.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - maybe not by definition but by usage, yes.

Comment: You can give examples where "to a fare-thee-well" is obviously being used to mean "tolerably well' rather than 1. [to a] condition [/in a manner] of utmost perfection: _played the part of the martyr to a fare-thee-well_.
2. [to t]he most extreme degree: _beat his opponent in the match to a veritable fare-thee-well_. [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fare-thee-well)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I hear "fairl well" used a lot.  If someone said, "That suit fits you fairly well."  That would be a compliment and means the suit fits really well (perhaps perfectly but what is that).  If someone said, "We beat that team fairly well last game."  I would take that to mean they blew them out and the game wasn't close.  Using the terminology of perfect is odd for a lot of examples where there is no perfection.  If a soccer team beats another 10-0 it's not perfection if the other team sucks.  Maybe they beat a great team 3-0 and played closer to perfection.

Comment: @RyeBread "fairly well" may be used in this sense in consonance with "fare-thee-well", uh?

Comment: @Nourished Gourmet: You have it the wrong way round. As Ryebread indicates, the "mock-archaic" form barely exists (nor ever did, frankly), so nothing would ever be used "in consonance" (or in any other relationship) to it, because hardly any people would have even heard of it.

Comment: @Edwin: According to OED, the US colloquialism *"fare-you-well"* dates back to at least 1884, defined as *to the last point; to the utmost degree; completely.* From which I'm tempted to suspect the *original* such usage was an allusion to the fact that *"Farewell"* is often ***the last word*** (we still say today that such-and-such is "the last word" [in high fashion, or whatever]). But the (very limited) "revival" in recent years might easily be influenced by assonance with *very/fairly well*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - very good stuff.  Will add it with a note.